# LRT in hypothesis testing

Tags: statistics

$X_1,\ldots,X_n$ is a random sample from $\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$

$$P(X=x)=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!}, x=0,1,2,3,\ldots$$

Consider the test:

$H_0: \lambda \le \lambda_0$ vs $H_1: \lambda > \lambda_0$

Show that the LRT gives a rejection region on the form $T>c$

The likelihood function is

$$L=\lambda^t e^{-n\lambda}\frac{1}{x_1! \cdots x_n!}$$

where $t=x_1+\cdots+x_n$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda} \log L=\frac t \lambda - n = 0$$

$\lambda=\frac{t}{n} $ maximizes $L$

it follows that if $\lambda_0 \le \frac{t}{n}$ LRT is:

$$\frac{\sup_{\lambda \le \lambda_0 L(\lambda\mid x_1,\ldots,x_n)}}{\sup_\lambda L(\lambda\mid x_1,\ldots,x_n)}= \left( \frac{\lambda_0}{t/n}\right)^te^{-n(\lambda_0-t/n)} = e^{t\log(\lambda_0)-t\log(t/n)-n \lambda_0+t}$$

How do I proceed from here to find the rejection region and to show that it is on the form $T>c$?

Comment: I took the liberty of changing $x=1,2,3,\ldots$ to $x=0,1,2,3,\ldots\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably already know everything below that comes before the line below that is labeled $(1),$ so you can consider the part above that to be an appendix for others who want to understand your question, and start reading after that.

You have
$$
\frac d {d\lambda} \log L(\lambda) = \frac t \lambda - n \quad \begin{cases} > 0 & \text{if } \lambda > t/n, \\ <0 & \text{if } \lambda > t/n. \end{cases}
$$
Therefore the value of $\lambda$ that maximizes $L(\lambda)$ on the interval $0\le\lambda\le\lambda_0$ is
$$
\begin{cases} \lambda_0 & \text{if } t/n \ge \lambda_0, \\ t/n & \text{if } t/n \le \lambda_0, \end{cases}
$$
(these two pieces agree when $t/n=\lambda_0$) and the value of $\lambda$ that maximizes $L(\lambda)$ on the interval $\lambda\ge 0$ is $t/n.$
The likelihood ratio is therefore
$$
\begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } t/n\le\lambda_0, \\[12pt] \dfrac{\lambda_0^t e^{-n\lambda_0}}{(t/n)^t e^{-t}} = \left( \dfrac{\lambda_0}{t/n} \right)^t e^{t-n\lambda_0} & \text{if } t/n\ge\lambda_0. \end{cases}
$$
The logarithm of that last expression is
$$
t\log\lambda_0 - t\log \frac t n + t - n\lambda_0. \tag 1
$$
The variable $t$ takes nonnegative integer values, so it may seem strange to differentiate with respect to it. But it is the restriction to integers, of a function of a real variable $t,$ and if we can show that is a decreasing function of $t$ on the interval $[\lambda_0,\infty),$ then we're done. We have
$$
\frac d {dt} \left( t\log\lambda_0 - t\log \frac t n + t - n\lambda_0 \right) = \log\left(\frac{\lambda_0}{t/n}\right).
$$
This is negative if $t/n > \lambda_0.$

Comment: can you explain why you get this interval [$\lambda_0 , \infty $] ? also why are you trying to show that it is a decreasing function of t? do you do that in general when using LRT? or is this things that completely depend on the test? (whether or not it is upper / lower / two tailed)? for instance if you consider the same problem, how would the situation be different if trying to apply LRT to the same problem but with $H_0:\lambda \ge \lambda_0$ vs $H_1: \lambda < \lambda_0$ instead? Also isn't the point of LRT to find a T that says something about when H_0 is rejected? What is T in this case?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer btw, but Also in the expression for type1 error. P(reject H_0|H_0 is true) that is just $P(T>c)=\alpha$ isnt it? (dependent on test I think, isnt it?) is the T that you find with LRT the same T that is used in this equation? or how exactly does this stuff work?

Comment: @stat333 : Your likelihood ratio has the maximized likelihood under the null hypothesis in the numerator, and the maximized likelihood found without assuming the null hypothesis in the denominator. That means the smaller the ratio, the stronger the evidence against the null hypothesis. So I showed that the ratio gets smaller as $T$ gets bigger. That means the bigger $T$ get, the stronger the evidence against the null hypothesis. That means the test that rejects the null hypothesis precisely if $T$ is too big is the likelihood ratio test. $\qquad$

Comment: After that, you just need to find the critical value $c$, so chosen that $\sup_\lambda \Pr( T>c \mid \lambda)$ does not exceed your significance level. $\qquad$

Comment: The interval of which I wrote was $[\lambda_0,\infty),$ not $[\lambda_0,\infty].$ Where I got it is where you got it: You wrote about it in the posted question.

Comment: so how would this stuff be different if the hypothesis test was in the other direction? $H_0: λ≥λ_0 $ vs $H_1:λ<λ_0$? and how can I find the c in this case?

Comment: I think I might understand now, because if T is large it makes the LRT smaller which means that its more likely to reject H_0 or something and that is the reason why we get the form: P(T>c)? if large T made the LRT larger then we would get P(T<c). Am I correct about that? I am getting really confused about this stuff, I am trying to get a good understanding about how LRT even works. I find hypothesis testing to be extremely difficult. so far atleast I understand the first thing of course, which is "setting up" the expression for the LRT which was what I in the question.

Comment: Correct. If you likelihood ratio had been the reciprocal of the one you used, then you would reject $H_0$ if the ratio is large, rather than if it is small. Since the ratio you used is small if and only if $T$ is large, the test that rejects $H_0$ if the ratio you used is small is the same as the test that rejects $H_0$ if $T$ is large. To establish that, it was enough to show that $T$ increases as the ratio decreases. $\qquad$

Comment: Do you know how I can find the LRT for geometric distribution testing $H_0: p \le p_0 $ vs $H_1: p > p_0$ ?

Comment: @stat333 : Certainly I can derive that.

Comment: could you please help me out with that? I'm trying to find a test for this hypothesis testing problem that I mentioned, so I suppose that I just use LRT to find $T$ ? isn't the first step to find the mle: $\hat p$, and then just plug $p_0$ into the simultaneous density in the numerator and plug $\hat p$ into the simultaneous density in the denominator?

I am not entirely sure how to continue from there (assuming what I mentioned is correct).

Comment: You plug $\widehat p$ into the "simultaneous density," in the numerator and what you plug into the density in the denominator is the quantity that maximimizes $L(p)$ under the null hypothesis, which is $\widehat p$ if that is $\le p_0$ and otherwise may be $p_0,$ except that you need to figure out what it is otherwise.

Comment: @stat333 : Could you post that as a separate question?